# GLM with exponential and linear terms (variable exposure)

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, model-selection

Suppose I'm counting the number of cars of a particular type that pass by a spot. I drive out to the spot at some time (that may differ depending on the day), sit there counting the cars, and note the count as well as when I arrived and left. I also note the type of weather on that day.

The general level of traffic depends on the day of week and hour of day, and if we suppose I'm counting say, open sports cars, the count would also depend on the weather.

If there had been no change in traffic from hour to hour, it'd seem reasonable to model the mean for day $i$ with weather and weekday effects as something like
$\mu_{i}=e^{\beta_{0}+\sum_{k=1}^{w}\beta_{k}weather_{ik}+\sum_{k=1}^{7}\beta_{1+k+w}weekday_{ik}}$, where $weather$ and $weekday$ are factors (with w and 7 levels respectively), since I'd imagine the effect of good weather would multiply the effect of more people driving on a weekend, say.

On the other hand, if weather is constant and the same amount of total traffic passes by every day, then it'd be more appropriate to select a linear model, $\mu_{i}=\sum_{k=1}^{24}hour_{ik}\beta_{k-1}$ (where $hour_{ik}$ is the fraction of the $k$th hour I spent observing traffic on day $i$) to get an idea of the relative traffic levels for each hour. The intuition would be that an unit period of time with high levels of traffic is equivalent to a long time with a reference level of traffic (assuming no traffic jams, etc.)

Is there any way to combine the two models, to determine the relative traffic levels for each hour while simultaneously determining the effects due to weather and day?

The first thing that came to mind was to perform a regression in two stages: first to find out the betas for each hour, then inserting these into an offset for the log-link regression. But suppose I happened to have stayed longer when it was sunny; then I imagine the interaction would make the traffic-per-hour estimates wrong.